# Angular 2 query parameters stay when switching to a new URL

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Here's an example. When I click the 'Logout' button, it redirects to the root path with query parameters `message=loggedout`. When I then click on the 'Sign In' button, and get redirected to the signin path, the `message=loggedout` parameters are still there - i.e.: `/signin?message=loggedout`

**App.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
import {AuthService} from '../../services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'nav',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [AuthService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  isLoggedIn = this._auth.isLoggedIn.check;
  constructor(private _auth: AuthService, private _router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  logout() {
        this._auth.logout()
            .then(() => { 
                    this._router.navigateByUrl('/?message=loggedout');
                }
            );
    }

}
```

**App.component.html**

```
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-wrapper" style='background-color: #226784'>
        <a class="brand-logo"[routerLink]="['/']">Site</a>
        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
          <li *ngIf="!isLoggedIn()"><a [routerLink]="['signin']" [queryParams]="">Sign In</a></li>
          <li *ngIf="!isLoggedIn()"><a [routerLink]="['signup']" [queryParams]="">Sign Up</a></li>
          <li *ngIf="isLoggedIn()"><a  (click)="logout()">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query parameters need to be explicitely reset.

This might work:

```
[queryParams]="{}">
```

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9573#issuecomment-228568695

Answer (score 2):

For the current release of Angular (RC.4) see Günter's solution/answer.

In the next release of Angular, this should be fixed -- i.e., query parameters will not persist when navigating to a new URL.

See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9924#issuecomment-231454941